# Gap at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css, vbulletin

I've almost finished designing the skin for my forums and I've had a gap at the bottom of the page, below the footer almost since I've started. I've found a number of similar questions and have tried all the suggestions but I can't seem to find the cause of the gap at the bottom of my forum webpage.

Forum : [Forum Link](http://forums.ministryofchat.com/forum.php)

I've checked all my margins and padding and they are all fine, and the problem seems to appear in all browsers.

Comment: Instead of fixed `padding-top` give the footer fixed *height* - for example setting height of 150px sorted things here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your

```
    body {overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: This is a really bad hack. It removes both sliders, horizontal and vertical. Then you end up with a "dead page". Adam would have had to fix his HTML/CSS to avoid the gap(s)...

Comment: I have often found that this is necessary on every page across a whole site, if that site uses Bootstrap. But as @AlexisWilke pointed out, it means that pages with content that doesn't fit within the browser height cannot be scrolled. I have previously hacked my way around this, but would finally like to know _why_ this is often necessary with Bootstrap, and what a better alternative would be (if one exists). P.S: I know for certain that the issue (at least in my case) is almost never caused by extraneous padding/margins.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Google Chrome Inspector` or `Firebug` for Firefox.

it is a simple CSS issue, you right click **INSPECT ELEMENT** and it will show you all CSS attributes on that element.

**About Chrome Inspector** *(example)*
http://www.threetipsaday.com/2008/12/debug-inspect-google-chrome-inspector/

[image]

**UPDATE**

It looks like the issue is the padding to me on your footer:

```
.footer {
    background: url("images/simplexity/backgrounds/background.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #33559B;
    border: 0 none;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font: 13px Tahoma,Calibri,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    margin-top: -80px;
    padding: 115px 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: Ive tried that, but it seems that it is cause by something else because when i inspect it it shows theres no padding or margins beyond where the background image on the footer is.

Comment: updated it with answer, its the footer, just right click **inspect**

Answer (score 3):

The gap is caused by the margin in your body-wrapper div.

`margin: -85px auto -60px auto` the '-60px' is the culprit (bottom-margin). Reduce or increase it to alter your gap.

[image]

Current:

```
.body_wrapper {
padding: 0px;
background: transparent none   ;
/*-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;*/
width: 960px;
margin: -85px auto -60px auto;
}
```

Reduced Gap:

```
.body_wrapper {
padding: 0px;
background: transparent none   ;
/*-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;*/
width: 960px;
margin: -85px auto -134px auto;    // CHANGE IS HERE
}
```

See? Less gap :) (margin-bottom: -134px)